# How can I open a document that Windows falsely alleges as 'moved or deleted'?

Tags: windows-explorer

Yesterday at 1 PM, I decided to move IPA.pdf from my Introductions, to my Linguistics, folder. As I had it open and was working with it, Windows couldn't move it. Not till 3 PM when I closed it, did Windows then move it. But today, I can't open it at all.

I tried [these 3 recommendations](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/cant-open-item-might-moved-renamed-deleted), but none worked:

> 1] Delete UserChoice folder from Registry Editor
> 2] Create new User Account
> 3] Use System File Checker (`sfc /scannow`)

[image]

#### Stopgap (This isn't a true solution as I don't know why it solved the difficulty.)

By chance, I aimlessly tried to  move the PDF to another folder (like Desktop), and it opened!

Comment: Are you double clicking the file to open it? Did you notice that the actual folder says “introductio” and the nitro pdf error says “introductions?” Did you rename the folder also? Have you run `chkdsk d: /f`? Are you navigating to this file through your documents library or have you gone to This PC -> D drive -> Documents -> Introductions etc...?

Comment: If your computer has backup enabled, you can restore it back to a state where the document was not moved.

Comment: What happens if you go to `D:\Documents\Introductions\Linguistics`?

Comment: @Appleoddity I didn't rename the folder; I think Windows just cut off the long folder name. I clicked on it and it still displays 'Introductions'. Yes to all your other questions.

Comment: @Attie Your first question overhead: I don't know why, sorry. Your 2nd question: Window brings me to that folder.

Comment: @S.Leon Sorry; I foolishly forgot to enable backup. But Windows 10 requires me to do so on an external drive?